# Xamarin cross platform app toolbar

Tags: xamarin

I'm new to xamarin and started a new cross platform project.  After doing some research I realized there is no toolbar.  All code must be written in xaml.  There is also a previewer built in that can preview as your coding which is nice but the question is, is there a 3rd party toolbar or framework where you can design your app and then convert it to xaml and thus copying that into your VS project. any ideas?

Comment: "All code must be written in XAML" is false.  And by "toolbar" to you mean "designer"?

Comment: I meant that there is no designer, it has to be written by code.. meaning xaml or c#. but looking for a designer with a toolbar that can convert to xamle